# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que al exportar mi tabla HTML a excel no aparezca un error de formato y extensión?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables

La función del exportar funciona bien, pero por lo que he investigado le falta los headers y no se como agregarlo a la siguiente función.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-buscar").click(function() {
    $("#tablaCotizaciones1").table2excel({

      filename: "RegistrosEntel" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\-\:\.]/g, ""),
      fileext: ".xls",

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo, que quites la imágen, y la pongas en formato de texto para que sea más legible y sea más fácil ayudarte..

Comment: cual es el error exacto? podrías agregar un ejemplo de tabla que se exporta? (ctrl+u o copiar nodo desde el inspector)

Comment: @aloMalbarez El error que me aparece al abrir el archivo excel que exporté y dice lo siguiente: El formato y la extensión de archivo de "archivo.xls" no coinciden.. Puede que el archivo esté dañado o noi sea seguro. No lo abra a menos que confíe en su origen.

Comment: Proba abrir el archivo con un bloc de notas, si es html entonces dependerá de la versión de excel mostrar esa alerta (versiones mas antiguas lo leen sin problemas, versiones mas nuevas no les gusta tanto el html)

Comment: como te dijeron mas arriba es con las versiones nuevas que hay problemas, te recomiendo usar esta librería: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx, incluso tiene una versión pagada en la que puedes personalizar la tabla con estilos y cosas de ese tipo